Error Starting Kernel - [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
After I installed Python 3.12.5 on my PC, I installed jupyter notebook using pip install notebook. After that, I tried to run jupyter notebook on command prompt and it opened. But when I try to use it, it shows an error like this.

When I look at cmd it shows the error like this.
[E 2024-12-11 02:52:25.760 ServerApp] [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 87, in wrapper
        out = await method(self, *args, **kwargs)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 439, in _async_start_kernel
        await self._async_launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 354, in _async_launch_kernel
        connection_info = await self.provisioner.launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\provisioning\local_provisioner.py", line 210, in launch_kernel
        self.process = launch_kernel(cmd, **scrubbed_kwargs)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 170, in launch_kernel
        raise ex
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 155, in launch_kernel
        proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)  # noqa
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
        self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
        hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[E 2024-12-11 02:52:25.766 ServerApp] [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 232, in _add_kernel_when_ready
        await kernel_awaitable
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\utils\__init__.py", line 198, in ensure_async
        result = await obj
                 ^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 784, in wrapped_method
        raise err
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 748, in wrapped_method
        out = await method(self, *args, **kwargs)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 853, in start_kernel
        return await super().start_kernel(*args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 96, in wrapper
        raise e
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 87, in wrapper
        out = await method(self, *args, **kwargs)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 439, in _async_start_kernel
        await self._async_launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 354, in _async_launch_kernel
        connection_info = await self.provisioner.launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\provisioning\local_provisioner.py", line 210, in launch_kernel
        self.process = launch_kernel(cmd, **scrubbed_kwargs)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 170, in launch_kernel
        raise ex
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 155, in launch_kernel
        proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)  # noqa
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
        self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
        hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[W 2024-12-11 02:52:25.772 ServerApp] 500 POST /api/sessions?1733860345564 (::1): [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[W 2024-12-11 02:52:25.773 ServerApp] wrote error: '[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 90, in post
        s_model = await sm.create_session(
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 285, in create_session
        kernel_id = await self.start_kernel_for_session(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 343, in start_kernel_for_session
        kernel_id = await self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 233, in _async_start_kernel
        kernel_id = await self.pinned_superclass._async_start_kernel(self, **kwargs)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 283, in _async_start_kernel
        raise km.ready.exception()  # type: ignore[misc]
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 232, in _add_kernel_when_ready
        await kernel_awaitable
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\utils\__init__.py", line 198, in ensure_async
        result = await obj
                 ^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 784, in wrapped_method
        raise err
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 748, in wrapped_method
        out = await method(self, *args, **kwargs)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 853, in start_kernel
        return await super().start_kernel(*args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 96, in wrapper
        raise e
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 87, in wrapper
        out = await method(self, *args, **kwargs)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 439, in _async_start_kernel
        await self._async_launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 354, in _async_launch_kernel
        connection_info = await self.provisioner.launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\provisioning\local_provisioner.py", line 210, in launch_kernel
        self.process = launch_kernel(cmd, **scrubbed_kwargs)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 170, in launch_kernel
        raise ex
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 155, in launch_kernel
        proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)  # noqa
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
        self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
        hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1790, in _execute
        result = await result
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\auth\decorator.py", line 73, in inner
        return await out
               ^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 108, in post
        raise web.HTTPError(500, str(e)) from e
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 500: Internal Server Error ([WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified)
[E 2024-12-11 02:52:25.778 ServerApp] {
      "Host": "localhost:8888",
      "Accept": "*/*",
      "Referer": "http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Untitled.ipynb",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
    }
[E 2024-12-11 02:52:25.779 ServerApp] 500 POST /api/sessions?1733860345564 (b56372ca7ef44cfbb6ea770509c6bcaf@::1) 210.24ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Untitled.ipynb

I already spent 12 hours trying to solve this. From install-reinstall some python version, restart the PC, look at others forums, etc. But none of them works in my case. Any suggestion?

Did you install a kernel? See here and the link to here. Here and other answers there may help you, too.

@Wayne Ah, I forgot to install the kernel. Thank you so much, sir.
